# Appending a scrollview (horizontal) to a view which has a scrollview (vertical) and two labels Iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1.2

I have developed an iphone application which has 6 cards (icons with images) in the Rootview. Clicking on a card would bring another view which the image being enlarged (fullScreen). The Card View has a Flip button which shows the back side of the Card which contains some text. Different cards hold different text on their back. Depending on the text size the view will be scrollable. I used two labels: one for title of the text and and second label having the whole paragraph. I have placed a scrollview below the two labels for vertical scrolling.

When a nth card is clicked from the Rootview the selected card should appear. It works perfectly. I used a separate view to design the front view of card and a different one for the text on the back. The issue is when a card is opened and flipped to see the text, it should be scrollable horizontally too apart from scrolling vertically. I dont want to redo anything. I have placed the vertical scrollview and the labels on the view representing back of card. I added another scrollview and enabled its paging property and wrote code in the following functions.

scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender;

scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)newScrollView.

But it is not working as desired. No scrolling works (even the vertical 1 which was earlier working fine. I mean when i combing the horizontal scrolling both stop working.
How do i allow vertical and horizontal scrolling to this view which has two labels.

I would appreciate your help...
Thanks in advance

Comment: One stupid question: are you setting the contentSize for all your scrollviews?

Comment: Hey not at all.
i m not setting the contentSize for both.
But why? what has that to do with this?
Sorry i dint get you!!

Comment: Just tell me the approach!!
With the approach of mine, even the already placed vertical scroll doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I used a table view to hold the card back details. So i get vertical scrolling by default.
I took a scrollview which will hold as many number of tableviews as there are cards.
And it is done